# gwt super dev mode appengine invalid

Tags: gwt

Launching gwt app in superdev mode, but getting com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration
below is the complete log.

Nov 09, 2016 5:46:49 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences 
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Loading modules
   com.nsn.caobusiness.ca.ui.CustomerAdmin
      Loading inherited module 'com.nsn.caobusiness.ca.ui.CustomerAdmin'
         [WARN] Line 48: Setting configuration property named 'devModeRedirectEnabled' in module 'com.nsn.caobusiness.ca.ui.CustomerAdmin' that has not been previously defined
Initializing App Engine server
Nov 09, 2016 5:46:54 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
SEVERE: Received exception processing C:\CA\AWCC CA\CustomerCare\target\CustomerCare-3.3\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate C:\CA\AWCC CA\CustomerCare\target\CustomerCare-3.3\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:141)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:75)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:165)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:414)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:159)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.(DevAppServerImpl.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:84)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\CA\AWCC CA\CustomerCare\target\CustomerCare-3.3\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:137)
    ... 24 more

[ERROR] Unable to start App Engine server
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration
Unable to start embedded HTTP server
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.reportDeferredConfigurationException(DevAppServerImpl.java:474)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:213)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid appengine-web.xml(C:\CA\AWCC CA\CustomerCare\target\CustomerCare-3.3\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml) - Could not locate C:\CA\AWCC CA\CustomerCare\target\CustomerCare-3.3\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:167)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:414)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:159)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:101)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:87)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.(DevAppServerImpl.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:258)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.access$000(DevAppServerFactory.java:36)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:226)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$1.run(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:84)
    ... 4 more
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:102)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:632)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1054)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:413)
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartupServer method

Checked other question but unable to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the appengine-web.xml in the WEB-INF with the OEM version. It appears to be corrupted.

Comment: I am trying to configure super dev mode in eclipse . For now I have not configured GAE in eclipse , only google plugin and GWT SDK has been configured, when i try to debug in GWT SDM i get this run time exception .